# What is the difference between FreeBSD/ARM and RaspBSD?

Tags: freebsd

There is a [page at the FreeBSD.org site](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi) that provides images for the Raspberry Pi. I've tried this and it works. There is also a separate site called [RaspBSD.org](https://www.raspbsd.org) that also provides what seems to be the same thing. They do not seem to be sync'ed as RaspBSD.org has the FreeBSD 11 image but not FreeBSD 12, while FreeBSD.org does.

What's the functional difference between these two? Are they the same thing? Is one more optimized? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  RaspBSD.org statement is pretty clear:

> The Goal of this project is to build images easily useable by anyone. Sometimes that means **images preloaded with different packages to help new users get started.** Initially they will start off pretty basic, but will expand in different directions to support different goals. Initial goals include Education and Entertainment. All of our images are built using publicly available tools and any enhancements will be pushed upstream.

Comment: Ahh. Yes, thanks. I must've been blind. It wasn't in the banner or the tagline or the huge "Image Information" section where you learn about the product. It was right there, at the very bottom of the page, inside what can be considered the fine print. I just installed FreeBSD from freebsd.org instead.